# Do you need to have the same mods locally in order to play on a modded server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods, minecraft-pixelmon

I want to get onto a Pixelmon server, but I'm wondering if I need the mod installed locally in order to be on the server?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you do.

Some mods do not need the Server to have it also installed, and vice versa.
IE: Optifine installed on client doesnt require it to be on the server.

But any mod that adds a new item/block for everyone to use will need to be installed on both your Minecraft and the server.